# how to add countdown timer in special module (opencart v.1.5.3.1)

Tags: opencart

I want to add countdown timer in special module(opencart 1.5.3.1) which displayed in homepage. looks like this
http://opencart-themes.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=109

anyone willing to help me? I tried a few times based on your code. it doesn't work.I really appreciate you can help me on this.

Comment: Have you done any of these steps? Have you added an expiration field to the back-end? Have you added it to the database? Have you changed the getProducts() function in model/catalog/product.php or called it in the controller/module/special.php?

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, I did it based on these code(see link), it's shown on product's page, I tried to change code in order to be shown special module, but failed.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759607/trying-to-add-jquery-countdown-timer-for-special-price-in-opencart

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly you have to fetch date_start and date_end from the database.** Edit catalog/model/catalog/product.php.

Change

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
    } else {
        $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
    }   

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY p.sort_order, p.date_expires >= NOW(), p.date_expires <= NOW() DESC");
```

To

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
    } else {
        $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
    }   

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT date_start FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS date_start, (SELECT date_end FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS date_ends, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY p.sort_order, p.date_expires >= NOW(), p.date_expires <= NOW() DESC");
```

**Note:** if you have edits in this and would like to preserve them, I only added the parts for those 2 values.

Then you need to send the value to the view file, you can do so in catalog/controller/module/special.php

```
        $this->data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
            'thumb'      => $image,
            'name'       => $result['name'],
            'price'      => $price,
            'special'    => $special,
            'rating'     => $rating,
            'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
            'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
        );
```

Change to:

```
        $this->data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
            'thumb'      => $image,
            'name'       => $result['name'],
            'price'      => $price,
            'special'    => $special,
            'rating'     => $rating,
            'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
            'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
            'date_start'     => $result['date_start'],
            'date_end'       => $result['date_end'],
        );
```

In catalog/view/theme/*your_theme*/template/module/special.tpl we need to do a few things. We need to Add the countdown script, add the countdown timer, and pull the values.

**1) Add the script** - There's also an if statement to only put the script if there is at least one special. Put this in the top of your tpl

```
<?php if ($products) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.fn.countdown = function (date, options, dateparse) {
    options = jQuery.extend({
        lang:{
            years:   [' year, ', ' years, '],
            months:  [' month, ', ' months, '],
            days:    [' day, ', ' days, '],
            hours:   [':', ':'],
            minutes: [':', ':'],
            seconds: ['', ''],
            plurar:  function(n) {
                return (n == 1 ? 0 : 1);
            }
        },
        prefix: "end: ",
        finish: "End!",
        redirect: '',
        dateparse: "2050-01-01 00:00:00" 
    }, options);

    var timestamp       = Date.parse(options.dateparse);

    var timeDifference  = function(begin, end) {
        if(end < begin){
            return false;
        }
        var diff = {
            seconds: [end.getSeconds() - begin.getSeconds(), 60],
            minutes: [end.getMinutes() - begin.getMinutes(), 60],
            hours: [end.getHours() - begin.getHours(), 24],
            days: [end.getDate()  - begin.getDate(), new Date(begin.getYear(), begin.getMonth(), 0).getDate()],
            months: [end.getMonth() - begin.getMonth()-1, 12],
            years: [end.getYear()  - begin.getYear(), 0]
        };

        var result = new Array();
        var flag = false;
        for(i in diff){
            if((i=='seconds' || i=='minutes') && diff[i][0]==0){
                result.push('00' + options.lang[i][options.lang.plurar(diff[i][0])]);
            }else{
                if(flag){
                    diff[i][0]--;
                    flag = false;
                }       
                if(diff[i][0] < 0){
                    flag = true;
                    diff[i][0] += diff[i][1];
                }
                if(!diff[i][0]) continue;
                if(i=='days' && diff[i][0]<0){
                    diff['days'][0]=Math.abs(1+diff['days'][0]);
                    diff['months'][0]++;
                }
                if(i=='years' && diff[i][0]<0)
                    return '';
                if((i=='seconds' || i=='minutes') && diff[i][0]<10)
                    diff[i][0]  = '0' + diff[i][0];

                if(diff[i][0]!=0)
                    result.push(diff[i][0] + '' + options.lang[i][options.lang.plurar(diff[i][0])]);
            }
        }
        return result.reverse().join('');
    };

    var timeCurrent = function(date){
        var hou     = date.getHours().toString();
        var min     = date.getMinutes().toString();
        var sec     = date.getSeconds().toString();
        hou         = (hou<10)?0+hou:hou;
        min         = (min<10)?0+min:min;
        sec         = (sec<10)?0+sec:sec;
        return hou+':'+min+':'+sec;
    };

    var elem        = $(this);
    var timeUpdate  = function(){
        dateJS      = new Date();

        timestamp   = parseInt(timestamp) + 1000;
        dateJS.setTime(timestamp);

        /*if(elem.parents('.timedependent-form-content').find('#currentTime').length)
            elem.parents('.timedependent-form-content').find('#currentTime').html(timeCurrent(dateJS));*/
        var s       = timeDifference(dateJS, date);
        if(s.length){
            elem.html(options.prefix + s);
        }else{
            clearInterval(timer);
            elem.html(options.finish);
            if(options.redirect != '')
                window.location.href    = options.redirect;
        }       
    };
    timeUpdate();
    var timer = setInterval(timeUpdate, 1000);      
};


</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Change

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
```

To:

```
<?php $now = time();
$count = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
$count++; ?>
```

Add this where you like:

```
<?php $time_remaining = $result['date_end'];
    $countdown = strtotime("$time_remaining"); ?>

  <div class="timerbar">
        <h2 id="product<?php echo $count; ?>"></h2>
    </div><br/>
    <script>
        jQuery("#product<?php echo $count; ?>").countdown(new Date(<?php echo date('Y, m, d, H, i, s',$countdown); ?>), {
                                                                prefix:"",
                                                                finish:"Expired",
                                                                redirect:"",
                                                                dateparse:"<?php echo date('d F Y H:i:s',$now); ?>",
                                                                lang:{
            years:   [' year, ', ' years, '],
            months:  [' month, ', ' months, '],
            days:    [' day, ', ' days, '],
            hours:   [':', ':'],
            minutes: [':', ':'],
            seconds: ['', ''],
            plurar:  function(n) {
                return (n == 1 ? 0 : 1);
            }
        }});
    </script>
```

**To customize the output:**

- `finish` = Expired text
- `redirect` = type url if you want it to redirect on expiration
- `lang` = Change countdown output

Comment: hi, I checked my opencart v1.5.3.1. It's different from your getProduct function.

Comment: Would you mind updating with the getProduct() that you have there?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, here is code:

```
public function updateViewed($product_id) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET viewed = (viewed + 1) WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
}

public function getProduct($product_id) {
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
    } else {
        $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
    }   

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

    if ($query->num_rows) {
        $query->row['price'] = ($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price']);
        $query->row['rating'] = (int)$query->row['rating'];

        return $query->row;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cleverbot answer is great but there is some missing or some error code was founded and the correct answer is as following :

**First step**:

Edit catalog/model/catalog/product.php.

change

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
} else {
    $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
}   

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY p.sort_order, p.date_expires >= NOW(), p.date_expires <= NOW() DESC");
```

to

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
} else {
    $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
}   

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT date_start FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS date_start, (SELECT date_end FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS date_ends, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY p.sort_order, p.date_expires >= NOW(), p.date_expires <= NOW() DESC");
```

and in same place file under above code search about

```
'special'          => $query->row['special'],
```

Then after Add this code

```
'date_ends'          => $query->row['date_ends'],
'date_start'          => $query->row['date_start'],
```

**Second Step:**

Then you need to send the value to the view file, you can do so in catalog/controller/module/special.php

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
        'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
        'thumb'      => $image,
        'name'       => $result['name'],
        'price'      => $price,
        'special'    => $special,
        'rating'     => $rating,
        'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
        'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
    );
```

to this one

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
            'thumb'      => $image,
            'name'       => $result['name'],
            'price'      => $price,
            'special'    => $special,
            'rating'     => $rating,
            'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
            'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
            'date_start'     => $result['date_start'],
            'date_ends'       => $result['date_ends'],

        );
```

**Third Step**

In **catalog/view/theme/*your_theme*/template/module/special.tpl** we need to do a few things. We need to Add the countdown script, add the countdown timer, and pull the values.

1) Add countdown script

put the following code in the top of special.tpl file (**important**)

```
<?php if ($products) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.fn.countdown = function (date, options, dateparse) {
options = jQuery.extend({
    lang:{
        years:   [' year, ', ' years, '],
        months:  [' month, ', ' months, '],
        days:    [' day, ', ' days, '],
        hours:   [':', ':'],
        minutes: [':', ':'],
        seconds: ['', ''],
        plurar:  function(n) {
            return (n == 1 ? 0 : 1);
        }
    },
    prefix: "end: ",
    finish: "End!",
    redirect: '',
    dateparse: "2050-01-01 00:00:00" 
}, options);

var timestamp       = Date.parse(options.dateparse);

var timeDifference  = function(begin, end) {
    if(end < begin){
        return false;
    }
    var diff = {
        seconds: [end.getSeconds() - begin.getSeconds(), 60],
        minutes: [end.getMinutes() - begin.getMinutes(), 60],
        hours: [end.getHours() - begin.getHours(), 24],
        days: [end.getDate()  - begin.getDate(), new Date(begin.getYear(), begin.getMonth(), 0).getDate()],
        months: [end.getMonth() - begin.getMonth()-1, 12],
        years: [end.getYear()  - begin.getYear(), 0]
    };

    var result = new Array();
    var flag = false;
    for(i in diff){
        if((i=='seconds' || i=='minutes') && diff[i][0]==0){
            result.push('00' + options.lang[i][options.lang.plurar(diff[i][0])]);
        }else{
            if(flag){
                diff[i][0]--;
                flag = false;
            }       
            if(diff[i][0] < 0){
                flag = true;
                diff[i][0] += diff[i][1];
            }
            if(!diff[i][0]) continue;
            if(i=='days' && diff[i][0]<0){
                diff['days'][0]=Math.abs(1+diff['days'][0]);
                diff['months'][0]++;
            }
            if(i=='years' && diff[i][0]<0)
                return '';
            if((i=='seconds' || i=='minutes') && diff[i][0]<10)
                diff[i][0]  = '0' + diff[i][0];

            if(diff[i][0]!=0)
                result.push(diff[i][0] + '' + options.lang[i][options.lang.plurar(diff[i][0])]);
        }
    }
    return result.reverse().join('');
};
var timeCurrent = function(date){
    var hou     = date.getHours().toString();
    var min     = date.getMinutes().toString();
    var sec     = date.getSeconds().toString();
    hou         = (hou<10)?0+hou:hou;
    min         = (min<10)?0+min:min;
    sec         = (sec<10)?0+sec:sec;
    return hou+':'+min+':'+sec;
};

var elem        = $(this);
var timeUpdate  = function(){
    dateJS      = new Date();

    timestamp   = parseInt(timestamp) + 1000;
    dateJS.setTime(timestamp);

    /*if(elem.parents('.timedependent-form-content').find('#currentTime').length)
        elem.parents('.timedependent-form-content').find('#currentTime').html(timeCurrent(dateJS));*/
    var s       = timeDifference(dateJS, date);
    if(s.length){
        elem.html(options.prefix + s);
    }else{
        clearInterval(timer);
        elem.html(options.finish);
        if(options.redirect != '')
            window.location.href    = options.redirect;
    }       
};
timeUpdate();
var timer = setInterval(timeUpdate, 1000);      
};
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

2) Add the countdown timer and pull the values.

Change

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
```

to

```
<?php $now = time();
$count = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
$count++; ?>
```

Add this where you like:

```
 <?php $time_remaining = $product['date_ends'];
$countdown = strtotime("$time_remaining"); ?>
 <div class="timerbar">
    <h2 id="product<?php echo $count; ?>"></h2>
</div><br/>
<script>
    jQuery("#product<?php echo $count; ?>").countdown(new Date(<?php echo date('Y, m, d, H, i, s',$countdown); ?>), {
                                                            prefix:"",
                                                            finish:"Expired",
                                                            redirect:"",
                                                            dateparse:"<?php echo date('d F Y H:i:s',$now); ?>",
                                                            lang:{
        years:   [' year, ', ' years, '],
        months:  [' month, ', ' months, '],
        days:    [' day, ', ' days, '],
        hours:   [':', ':'],
        minutes: [':', ':'],
        seconds: ['', ''],
        plurar:  function(n) {
            return (n == 1 ? 0 : 1);
        }
    }});
</script>
```

To customize the output:

- `finish` = Expired text
- `redirect` = type url if you want it to redirect on expiration
- `lang` = Change countdown output

All of These codes is working well with me , hope to work with you

i tried it with opencart v.1.5.6.4 and it is work